# Laravel join with pagination

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, join, pagination

I am using laravel(v-5.6) pagination. I have two tables : table1 size ~1.6 Million rows and table2 size ~0.8 Million rows. I am performing join operation based on some condition. My query is as follows -

```
$results = $connection->table('table1' as db1")
                ->select('db1.id as kuchikomi_id','db1.comment as splitted_kuchikomi','db1.kuchikomi_sentiment','db1.status as kuchikomi_status','db2.id','db2.hotel_id','db2.comment','db2.post_date','db2.ota_name','db2.negative_comment','db2.positive_comment','db2.language')
                ->Join('table2' as db2", 'db1.kuchikomi_id', '=', 'db2.id')
                ->where('db1.kuchikomi_language', $language)
                ->whereIn('db1.id', $splitted_id))
                ->paginate(100);
```

here $splitted_id is a collection of ~0.6 Million ids. When I execute this query it takes more than 12 minutes and terminates because of maximum execution time exceeds.

table1 indices -

- db1.kuchikomi_language
- db1.id

My question is- Is join operation suitable for this size of tables? if yes how can I improve execution time? Need some help to figure out these doubts. Thank you.

Comment: A join should not be a problem on multi million record tables. But do you have any indexes on these tables?

Comment: Is it faster when you remove the where statements and the pagination?

Comment: @Jerodev Yes, for table1 2 indexes 1. on kuchikomi_language, 2. on comment. id is primary key.

Comment: @piscator : yes, it gives result in 20 seconds.

Comment: can you check them seperately to understand what makes the problem?

Comment: I agree with @piscator, one more thing I want to mention is that I don't think `paginate` is optimal here since it needs to fetch the count of retrieved rows, which, if the data is big, might add up, try replacing `paginate` with `take` just to make sure if you get the data faster

Comment: @NikolaGavric: I tried replacing paginate() with take(). It is still taking longer time. I think to fetch the count of retrieved rows may take some time but significantly less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the where statements are the cause of the performance issue, you could try to create a composite index for `db1.kuchikomi_language` and `db1.id`, by executing this in a migration:

```
$table->index(['kuchikomi_language', 'id']);
```

That will speed the `where('db1.kuchikomi_language', $language)` statement.

After that, you could try to use a filter instead of the `whereIn('db1.id', $splitted_id))` statement, if this part of the query takes a long time to execute. You can analyse this by using the [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

That will give you the possibility to cache the results before and / or after the filtering of the splitted id's, depending on how long the filtering takes.

The pagination is probably not the cause of the performance issue, but it is good to analyse this as well.